# Why ref from weakref library not dead when delete function?

Tags: python

I have tried:

```py
import weakref

def test_weakref():
    print('test')

a = weakref.ref(test_weakref)

del test_weakref

print(a)
```

it show:

```
<weakref at 0x7fe80e43bea8; to 'function' at 0x7fe81d1c0ea0 (test_weakref)>
```

Why a variable not dead when I del test_weakref function?

Comment: [Can't reproduce.](https://ideone.com/ompQoF) It's likely that you accidentally kept another reference to `test_weakref` in your actual experiment, and you didn't accurately report what you did.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKE8NTG7KDWNiyslNU2hJLW4JB4qoqFpxaUABAVFmXklGuogKXVNLq5EBVuYHj2QKmQtmiBTclBM4eKC6E/U/P8fAA "Python 3 – Try It Online"); how are you executing this, with what interpreter and version? Are you sure you didn't accidentally save off a copy, even inadvertently (an exception's traceback contains references to the frames it was raised in for instance, which would keep names alive).

Comment: @user2357112 I have tried, it has dead, I don't know why?

Comment: @ShadowRanger I have executed it, I run on python 3.6.8. I have tried with another terminal it work well, I don't know why